# Probability of more than n machines down any hour?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have $N$ identical machines, at any given hour, there's a chance $P$ that any given machine went down. A down machine takes $T$ hours to recover. How do I calculate the chances that in a given longer interval $Y$ (assume $Y >> T$), what are the probability that there exists hour $t$, $0 < t < Y$, such that at $t$ there are more than $R$ machines that are down?

Comment: A Poisson distribution describes this situation.

Comment: Do you want to know the probability more than $R$ machines are down at time $Y$ or the probability that there exists time $0<t<Y$ such that more than $R$ machines are down at time $t$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft, the later, the probability that there exists time 0 < t < Y such that more than R machines are down at time t.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, how would I apply Poisson distribution to this scenario? I can maybe find the average number of machines going down per year based on the `P`, and calculate the chances for r < `R`, but that does not necessarily answer if they are concurrent?

Comment: This is a Poisson distribution with expected number of faults in a given hour of $P N$.  That determines all probabilities.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Except if a machine is broken it can't break in the next hour, so the expected number of faults each hour isn't $PN$, it's $PK$ where $K$ is the number of currently working machines.